# php mail is not working

Tags: php

php mail is not working. no error messages. php.ini has display errors on and show E_ALL is also on.

```
<?php
 $to = "test@abc.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = 'From: test@abc.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: test@abc.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

 ?>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working then?

Comment: im not getting the email

Comment: mail() has a boolean return type. Checking what it is tells whether the mail is actually sent or not.

Comment: it's not there in my spam folder

Comment: i did echo mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); it returns nothing

Comment: check it with an `if` statement.

Comment: The return code of `mail()` only tells you that the message has been accepted for delivery. SMTP (=the e-mail protocol) doesn't guarantee when a message will be delivered, or even whether it'll be delivered at all. See also the docs (under "Return Values") http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: there was no return value. 
echo mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); prints nothing

Comment: Sent as in to the SMTP-server that is. What do you mean no luck?

Comment: what is the mailserver you are sending your mails from?

Comment: This looks like a pretty comprehensive guide to troubleshooting e-mail issues: http://support.kavi.com/khelp/kmlm/user_help/html/troubleshooting_intro.html

Comment: no luck was in response to "check it with an if statement"

Comment: echo doesn'T print boolean values! use var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers));

Comment: ITroubs .. I tried echo var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers));  it returns bool(false)

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: From where are you sending it from? A remote server? Local machine?

Comment: sending it from a remote server

Comment: "it returns bool(false)" - you have some error in your message, or in the php.ini settings (for the SMTP server). Some servers are configured to reject mails from remote hosts - check your SMTP server's config if that's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check the return value of `mail()`

```
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if (!$sent) {
    // there was some error in the message itself, our MTA rejected it or there's an error in MTA's config
} else {
    // message was accepted for delivery
}
```

Second, check [PHP's e-mail settings](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) (note that on a Linux server the `sendmail_path` is relevant, whereas on Windows servers it's `SMTP` and `smtp_port`) try to send an e-mail with them from another application.

Third, depending on the SMTP server you use, check its logs for any warnings or errors (e.g. cannot contact destination server, not connected to network, etc.).

Fourth, if you have ascertained that the mail has succesfully left your network, cross your fingers and hope for the best. Seriously, there's nothing more that you can do for your e-mail message from that point onwards - and if it doesn't get delivered, there's not much you can do.

Check out also [these tips](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) on *slightly* increasing the chance that your mail won't be marked as spam

Comment: SMTP server settings are ignored under linux. Path to sendmail needs to be correct and sendmail has to be installed however.

Comment: @Alexander Sagen: The linked PHP documentation page does explain this. Edited to clarify. Also, it can be anything that can pose as sendmail, most modern MTAs install a symlink to themselves from /usr/sbin/sendmail .

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all so much for the replies. It was really helpful. It was a permission issue

drwxrwx---  2 smmsp smmsp 4096 Oct 12 12:00 /var/spool/clientmqueue/

changed above to

drwxrwx---  2 apache smmsp 4096 Oct 12 12:56 /var/spool/clientmqueue/

and it worked!